# Comment exprimer "any" en français ?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

> La Corée du Nord a joué toutes ses cartes sur la table avant que les États-Unis n’aient relevé des sanctions.

Deux questions sur la phrase ci-dessus :

1. Est-ce qu’il est correct d’utiliser le subjonctif passé après *Les États-Unis*, ou est-ce qu’on aurait dû utiliser le subjonctif présent ?
2. Ce que je veux exprimer est « before the US have lifted any sanctions ».  Pour exprimer le sens du mot « any » en français, quel est le mot le plus approprié ?  Est-ce qu’on peut dire, par exemple :

> "avant que les États-Unis n’aient relevé aucune sanctions"

Comment: Pouvez-vous expliquer le sens de la première partie de la phrase en Anglais ou par une périphrase en Français ? Tel quel, ce n'est pas évident d'identifier de quelle nuance de "jouer des cartes" il s'agit.

Answer (score 3):

So, before I answer you questions, there is a few points to correct in your sentence :

-the expression is "abattre (toutes) ses cartes".

-the verb "relever" means that your "lift something up again" as the prefix "re" indicates and in this context does not fit. Also, in the context of sanctions the verb "lever" is always used.

1. If you want to say that up until right now no sanction have been lifted you should use the sub present.
   "les Etats-Unis ne lèvent..."

If you want to say that no sanctions have been lifted up until a certain  point in the past, you should use the following : "
"les Etats-Unis n'aient levé", so if that was your intention you were right !

2. This is sa tricky one, there is no word in french that can translate "any" right away. It really depends on the context and sometimes it is better not to translate it at all. But in your case I would translate it as "toute". It is a weird way to use "tout" but in this sense it means that "all the sanctions are still in place".

And unfortunatley "aucun(e)" really only means "no, none". There is also another possibility that is more formal, which is the one I would recommend if you were to write that in a text. It is the use of "quelconque", but I emphasize that really few people use that orally.

So, to sum up your sentence should be something like that :

A: La Corée du Nord a abbatu toutes ses cartes avant que les Etats-Unis ne lèvent toute sanction.

B:La Corée du Nord a abbatu toutes ses cartes avant que les Etats-Unis n’aient levé toute sanction.

C: (the most formal) La Corée du Nord a abbatu toutes ses cartes avant que les Etats-Unis n’aient levé quelconque sanction.

Orally, I would use A: and written C:.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange !

Comment: L'expression que l'on cherche à traduire est clairement *play all one's card*, qui ne se traduit pas par *jouer cartes sur table* ("être honnête") mais plutôt *jouer son va-tout* ou *abattre ses cartes* ("accomplir une maneuvre finale ou de dernier ressort").

Comment: Tout à fait ! J'avais pas compris ainsi en lisant la phrase pour la première fois. Et donc effetcivement, abattre ses cartes me semble le plus pertinent. J'ai édité ma réponse.

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you want is:

> *La Corée du Nord a joué toutes ses cartes<sup>1</sup> avant que les États-Unis n’aient levé **quelque sanction que ce soit**.*

or maybe:

> *La Corée du Nord a **posé** toutes ses cartes **sur la table**<sup>2</sup> avant que les États-Unis n’aient levé quelque sanction que ce soit.*

*Quelque xxx que ce soit* might be replaced by *une quelconque xxx*:

> *La Corée du Nord a joué toutes ses cartes avant que les États-Unis n’aient levé **une quelconque sanction**.*

About the subjunctive past or present, both can be used:

> *La Corée du Nord a joué toutes ses cartes avant que les États-Unis ne lèvent **quelque sanction que ce soit**.*

Reading again the sentences, I think I wouldn't have used *avant* but *sans*:

> *La Corée du Nord a joué toutes ses cartes **sans** que les États-Unis n’aient levé **une quelconque** sanction.*

or

> *La Corée du Nord a joué toutes ses cartes **sans** que les États-Unis n’aient levé **la moindre** sanction.*

<sup>1</sup><sub>Elle a épuisé ses moyens de pression</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Elle a divulgué tout ce qu'elle pouvait utiliser comme moyen de pression</sub>